# How to use a non-default constructor in Universal Windows Apps

Tags: mvvm, inversion-of-control, win-universal-app

I'm just getting started trying to create a Universal Windows App and am attempting to implement it using MVVM along with dependency injection.

With my View I have a single line in the constructor that sets the ViewModel field.

```
public sealed partial class Login : Page
{
    private readonly LoginViewModel ViewModel;

    public Login(LoginViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = viewModel;
    }
}
```

I also need to inject a dependency into this particular view model. Ideally all of these would be set up through registration with the IoC container (Autofac). However at the moment the main stumbling block I am hitting is the way that the navigation occurs in UWP -

```
rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(Login));
```

I just specify the type and have no control over the instantiation of the object. Does anybody know how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Zak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a temporary sollution, you can pass LoginViewModel as secondary parameter of `Navigate` method, and retrived it in `NavigatedTo` method of the page.

if you want to be more flexible, I would recommend MVVM Light library. It provide Service locator which helps you create ViewModel for each page.

Comment: Thanks. I had seen lots of references to MVVM Light and also Prism around just wasn't sure if there was some other way of implementing DI kind of like the DependencyResolver in MVC.